# Добавление нового функционала в програмный продукт

Tags: delphi, база-данных

Здравствуйте! У меня тут такая ситуация. На работе, один программист написал программу для загрузки планов гос.закупок с последующим анализом рынка сбыта товаров. Моя задача такая: необходимо с помощью delphi 7 добавить в эту программу такую функцию, чтоб. к примеру, можно было выбрать какую-либо компанию с ее загруженными планами по гос.закупкам и удалить все данные загруженные в данную компанию. Примерно, это должно выглядеть так: открываем окно с загруженными компаниями, кликаем на нужную компанию и удаляем всю базу, которую содержит данная компания.

Comment: ale_x я ознакомился в крации с вашей ссылкой, на сколько я понял там информация по склейке exe файлов, но пока мне это не нужно. мне для начала необходимо написать данную функцию в delphi. я бы хотел услышать от вас с помощью каких компонентов это можно сделать, спасибо.

Comment: Вот и спросите у тех, что дали, что они точно хотят. Взамен ничего, напишите им программу. Бред. Некорректно поставлена задача, БД нет, кода нет, напишите, чтобы удаляло.

Answer (score 2):

Добавить свой функционал в чужую программу возможно. Это хорошая новость. Взять те же crack'и и некоторые патчи - они видоизменяют код оригинальной программы, чтобы включить или добавить возможноссть выполнения отдельных ф-ций. Плохая новость - Вам это не под силу. Для этого нужно хорошо разбираться в архитектуре ПК, уметь писать на ассемблере, уметь работать с дизассемблерами и отладчиками, т.е.копаться на самом низком уровне ПО. К тому же Дельфи для таких вещей далеко не лучший инструмент.

Если задача стоит обработка данных из уже существующей БД, то для начала пишите отдельную программу на Дельфи, которая будет делать с данными, что необходимо. А дальше смотрите по обстоятельствам. Если алгоритм будет отлажен, то его можно переписать на многие другие языки без особых проблем, а если найдутся исходные коды оригинального продукта, то и без проблем внедрите в него свой функционал

Answer (score -1):

Если есть исходники - то без проблем можно добавить,
Если исходников нет -> самое простое написать отдельную программу - которая будет работать данные с этой же Базой( из вашего вопроса я понял что все сохраняется в базу).

Comment: Да все в mysql сохраняется, и мне желательно написать отдельную программу. точнее мне нужно сделать отдельную программу а затем добавить ее в ту самую программу о которой я говорил. не подскажите с помощью каких элементов это сделать.

Comment: А первая (которую програмист писал) на чем сделана?

Comment: блин точно не знаю, но точно не delphi. а это важно да?

Comment: Просот я не понимаю к чему такая сложность - добавлять в чужую программу с помощью DELPHI Дополнительный функционал.
Возможно и важно на чем сделано - может это сделано в виде серверного  скрипта (на php к примеру) и вы работайте через браузер - тогда проще простоко переделать исходники и все)

Вам может проще поставить задачу: нужна программа аналогичная существующей но с дополнительным функционалом (удаление компаний и ее загруженных планов закупок)- я прав?

Comment: Короче ситуация такова, мне дали это задание можно сказать с какой-то стороны для проверки моих знаний delphi но я с delphi только можно сказать знакомлюсь. может и проще сделать это с помощью исходников но мне необходимо просто добавить эту функцию в данную программу, и исходников у меня нет чтоб их переделать к сожалению. помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Данную операцию по удалению можно конечно проделать и с помощью MySQL но хотелось бы как то по мобильнее.

Comment: Если дело обстоит так - то тут нада читать и читать 
вот пример что требуют тебя  http://www.xakep.ru/post/38421/?print=true